# How to adjust the setting file to have the smallest (lightest) django source?

Tags: python, django

I want to build a lightest django source and how to set it in the `settings.py`

As I notice, whenever I build and migrate a django source. There are tables which will be migrate by default such as:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
...
django_admin_log
django_content_type
...
```

In the situation, that I only need to build a source that server a couple of tables and CRUD (create, retrieve, update, delete) rows on that table. I dont need `auth` and `django` things. What should I do ?

Comment: did you try to remove unnesessary app name from setting.py ?

Comment: How about `MIDDLEWARE` , anything that we can remove as well ? @AhmadAkelOmar

Comment: no no need , just remove app name from  INSTALLED_APPS list